# firefox not opening using browser in selenium python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Firefox Browser is not opening when i running a code:

`browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

it showing the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 91, in <module>
    Main()
  File "code.py", line 74, in Main
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Help..

Comment: always use the generic Python tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path to the `executable_path`:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'YourPathTo/geckodriver')
```

And make sure that your geckodriver is executable:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```